# Cannot save multiple images from a single image opencv (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, image, opencv, save

i am using opencv 3.1 with Eclipse to divide an image in more images.
The problem is that when i try to save them, only the first of 9 images (for example) is saved.
The odd thing is that the console says the images are saved but i can see only one.
The code is the following:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Range;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class prova {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME ); 

    Imgcodecs imageCodecs = new Imgcodecs(); 

       String file 
="C:/Users/Zast/Desktop/workspacePR2/tesina/images/img.jpg"; 
      Mat mat= imageCodecs.imread(file); 

      System.out.println("Image Loaded");     



   // Creating an empty matrix to store the result
     // Mat dst = new Mat();

       for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
             for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
            int a1=i*200;
            int b1=i*200+199;
            int a2=j*200; 
            int b2=j*200+199;
            Mat mat2= mat.submat(a1,b1,a2,b2); 
            imshow ("filtro", mat2);

            String file2 = 
"C:/Users/Zast/Desktop/workspacePR2/tesina/images/img1.jpg";

            imageCodecs.imwrite(file2, mat2); 
            System.out.println("Image Saved ............"); 
             }}
}



    private static String String(int i) {

    return null;
}



    public static void imshow(String windowname, Mat m){
        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
        if ( m.channels() > 1 ) 
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
        int bufferSize = m.channels()*m.cols()*m.rows();
        byte [] b = new byte[bufferSize];
        m.get(0,0,b); // get all the pixels
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(m.cols(),m.rows(), type);
        final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) 
        image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, targetPixels, 0, b.length);
        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(image);
        JFrame frame=new JFrame(windowname);
        JLabel lbl=new JLabel(icon);
        frame.add(lbl);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

      System.out.println("Image Processed");
   } }
```

The output console is the following:

```
Image Loaded
Image Processed
Image Saved ............
Image Processed
Image Saved ............
Image Processed
Image Saved ............
Image Processed
Image Saved ............
Image Processed
Image Saved ............
Image Processed
Image Saved ............
Image Processed
Image Saved ............
Image Processed
Image Saved ............
Image Processed
Image Saved ............
```

Comment: If the filename for the output is always the same in each iteration of the for loop.... then you will have only one file saved (should be the last one you process)... Try to vary "img1.jpg" every iteration, like img2.jpg, img3.jpg and so on

Comment: Yes, it worked, i missed this thing. Thank you very much :D .